# Is it possible to increase a camera's burst shooting FPS through software changes?

Tags: canon, burst-mode

The Canon 77D has a burst shooting rate of 6fps and Canon 80D, 7 fps. Knowing fully well the fps is dependent on the camera body, is it possible to increase the fps at least by a single point by  software/firmware changes (like "overclocking" of CPU)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Maybe not.

Frame rates in some cameras can be "throttled" somewhat. This allows camera makers to use common parts for models with performance that is differentiated by price in their product lines. But other cameras can also already be at the hardware limits of the motors moving things such as mirrors and shutter curtains.

In the first case it *might* be possible, but I've never heard of anyone actually trying to do it. As much work as has been done by the folks at Magic Lantern, one would think that if this were even remotely practical someone would have done it for one of the Canon models supported by MAgic Lantern.

You'd need to write your own complete firmware to replace Canon's. Even if you do have such programming skills, along with the ability to crack the current firmware, the time investment needed to do it would likely *far* outweigh the current $250 difference between the price of the 80D and The 77D. Not to mention that one single mistake could irrevocably brick the camera in question.

Beyond that, max frame rates are a little overly optimistic anyway. To get the maximum frame rate out of any DSLR, one needs to turn off AF, set ISO, Tv, and Av manually, turn off any lens correction, turn off things such as 'Highlight Tone Priority' and 'Auto Lighting Optimizer', etc. Some testers go so far as to test all cameras for max frame rate with the lens cap on to reduce the amount of variety in the recorded frame which makes processing and compression easier.

Comment: I could swear my Canon 7D got a firmware upgrade (from Canon) at some point that added a "high speed continuous" mode that took if from something like 8fps to 13 or 18fps. I don't recall them saying what changed to make it possible though.

Comment: @user1118321 - There was an improvement, but it didn't increase the framerate. That was physically limited. What Canon did to was provide a firmware upgrade that would increase the buffering limit of raw images from about 15 to 25. Thus you could shoot at 7fps for about 3.5 seconds instead of the original 2.

Comment: Yeah, the frame rate was the same (8 fps) before and after the firmware 2.x update. What changed was how long it could go until the buffer filled and bogged things down to about 2 fps. Canon claimed it was due to better lossless compression algorithms and fewer lines of code that streamlined processing. Most critics said Canon didn't want to admit the buffer had been firmware limited to keep the 7D buffer (17 raw) shorter than the 1D Mark IV (28 raw). Once the 1D X came out in March 2012 (38 raw), then Canon unlocked the full buffer in the 7D (25 raw) with the firmware update in August 2012.